# Android AlarmManager receiver not being called when app is removed from recently used list

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I'm writing an App that will set up a number of alarms to tell one of my relatives when to take their tablets and Insulin, they have Diabetes. I have been trying to use AlarmManager to do this, I can get it to work when the App is active or when its in the background but not when it's been closed. According to the Android documentation

**Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.**

I have searched the internet looking for a solution but I can't find one, a fair few have the same problem as me but none of the suggestions I've found work. The only thing I can think of is to start my alarms in a service and keep the service running. Again, the documentation to me says I shouldn't have to do this. Can anyone help?

Example code

Start Alarm

```
Calendar setcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
setcalendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, cls);
intent1.putExtra("Alarm", "First");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, DAILY_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE, intent1, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setcalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Receiver just sends a notification and logs the event. I am running this under Android 10.

When I use adb to check for any waiting alarms mine does not appear when the App is closed, but it does if the App is running or in the background.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Lee.

Comment: I've also tried WorkManager, again it works if the app is active or in the background but not when the app is closed? Again the notes for WorkManager say this is meant to work when the app is closed?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "closed"?  As in, force stopped?

Comment: Hi Ryan. Yes. I think I've found a solution in the last few hours by adding the flag         Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to my Intent it appears to be working now. Would you know if this is the right thing to do or is there an alternative to my initial code? Thanks. Lee.

Comment: After a bit more investigation this is what happens, on first run if I force stop my app the alarm is not set, as seen in adb. On the second run of my app the alarm gets set and is called even after a force stop this is expected functiomality after the first run, what could be causing the alarm to be not set after the first run? No changes to code in between runs exactly the same code gets executed.

Comment: Another bit of information, I am not Force Stopping the app I am just removing it from the most recently used list, I can see why the alarms would stop if I was force stopping the app.

Comment: The problem is a bug in android studio, beleive it or not. If I run the app on my device not connected to android studio it works perfectly as expected. See   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150080941#comment5 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149556385